# How to automatically do access rights for people across files in Sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint-online

Once I add list of people to a document say Excel and uploaded to Sharepoint online, is it possible to carry forward the same list when I take a copy of that excel without me adding manually everytime? I need to give access to same people every quarter to the document.
I tried searching Google and also in MS sharepoint portals but didn't get good solution till now.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint, you may use organizations and permission levels to control get right of entry to to files and folders across the web page. Here are the steps to robotically observe get right of entry to rights to humans throughout documents in SharePoint:

Create businesses: You can create businesses based totally on the sort of customers and the extent of get right of entry to they want. For example, you can create a group for challenge participants who need full get admission to to the project folder, and some other group for stakeholders who most effective need examine-best get admission to.

Assign permission tiers: SharePoint has predefined permission stages consisting of Full Control, Design, Edit, Read, etc. You can assign those permission degrees to the companies you created.

Add customers to groups: Once the corporations and permission stages are installation, you may add users to an appropriate corporations based totally on their roles and obligations.

Set up inheritance: SharePoint permits you to inherit permissions from parent folders to baby folders. You can installation inheritance to ensure that the get admission to rights of customers are regular throughout all documents in a specific folder or subfolder.

Automate get right of entry to rights: You can use SharePoint workflows to automate the process of assigning get entry to rights to customers based on predefined policies and conditions. For instance, you may set up a workflow to routinely add new customers to the right agencies once they join the organization.

Test and reveal: It is critical to test the access rights and display them regularly to make certain that they are working as supposed. You can use SharePoint's auditing features to track who has accessed documents and folders and what modifications they've made.

By following these steps, you could ensure that get right of entry to rights are automatically implemented to people throughout documents in SharePoint, making it less difficult to manage get entry to and preserve security.

Comment: Thanks for sharing lot of details but in order for me to get clarity can you please share documents for each section mentioned so I can find answer to the specific problem I have. Thank you.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).